# Check for movement in a small area in video in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I've got a video stream from the camera. My goal is to detect and track position of moving object (train).

First of all I tried to use movement detection (frames difference, background subtractors) but it gave bad results.
Tried to cling to the color of the object but it's often (bad lighting, blurry) the same color as a ground (railways).

So the current approach is to divide the area of movement of object into n small regions and define difference between the stored region when there's no object and current one.

The main problem in here is that lightness is changing and when I use a stored region from a reference frame (where there's no object) the brightness of the current frame might be different and it breaks it up.
Also brightness can change while object moving.
It helps me to apply a gaussianBlur and histogramEqualization to make sensitivity to changes in brightness a bit less.

I tried to compare a structure of according regions using ssim, lbph, hog. When I test lbph and hog approaches on the manual cropped regions which is larger than real ones it looked like working but then I used them for my small regions and it stopped working.

In the moment the most efficient approach is just difference between grayscale regions with rmse using a fixed thresholds but it's not robust approach and it suffers a lot when brightness is changing.

Now I'm trying to use some high-pass operator to extract the most dominant edges like with sobel operator in the attached figure but I'm not sure how to properly compare the high-passed regions except by finding the difference.

[image: empty and occluded regions with sobel operator applied]

Frame with an empty railway:
[image: Frame with an empty railway]

In some seconds a train is appeared and luminance was changed.
[image: Frame with occlusion was changed in brightness]

At night time luminance is also different.
[image: Luminance at night]

So the questions are:

1. What approaches are there for comparison of high-passed images?
2. Is there any other way to determine if an area is overlapped which you could suggest me?

Comment: I think you'll have to supply some frames for your application. It's not clear whether you truly want to track **position** of a train or the **existence** of a train in the frame? Also, it's not clear what the lighting problem is. Does ambient light change through the day and that is the issue? Or the lighting appears to change when a train goes by? Depending on some of these details, the nature of the appropriate solution is different.

Comment: @bfris, supplied some more data, hope it'll help